# GZIP used improperly for zipping multiple files

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, gzip

I ran the command `gzip` (to get `data.gz`) on a group of files, now when I run gunzip, I get just one file. I understand that I should have used tar to preserve the file structure. But, can I get the separate files now?

Directory had two files `1.sas7bdat`, `2.sas7bdat`. I ran:

```
$ gzip -c *.sas7bdat | ssh -l adsusername newserver.com 'cat > /home/username/data.gz'
```

Now when I run:

```
gunzip data.gz
```

I get just one file, data. I'd want to have 1.sas7bdat and 2.sas7bdat

Comment: What is the exact command? could this be a bit more elaborated ?

Comment: Added details to question

Comment: Normally gzip would compress each individual file it's given in its arguments. So 1.sas7bdat.gz and 2.sas7bdat.gz, and give you an error about 'no such file or directory' for data.gz...

Comment: But can I not get the individual files back again, using some eof flag within the single file etc.?

Answer (score 1):

If that literally was the command you used, then you have no problem. However there should also not be a `data.gz` file resulting, unless it was already there. There would have been an error whether or not a `data.gz` file already existed in that directory. Either you would get `gzip: data.gz already has .gz suffix -- unchanged` or `gzip: data.gz: No such file or directory`.

The names on the gzip command line are *individually* compressed, and produce *distinct* files, one for each file on the command line. What results from `gzip file1 file2 file3` are the files file1.gz, file2.gz, and file3.gz. All you need to do to recover those files is `gunzip *.gz`.

*Update:*

Now that we see the *actual* command you used, you can look through the file to try to determine where the first one ended and the second one begins.

Your use of the `-c` option wrote the compressed data to stdout, which concatenated the two input files before compressing them. So the end result after `gunzip data.gz` is the same as `cat *.sas7bdat > data`.

However, the `data.gz` file does have the two files secretly separated internally, though there are no utilities to extract them separately. You can write your own program using [zlib](http://zlib.net/) to extract a member at a time, and write them to separate files. The `inflateInit2`, `inflate`, `inflateEnd` functions, with the proper options to select the gzip format, will only extract one member at a time.

Comment: $ gzip -c *.sas7bdat | ssh -l adsusername newserver.com 'cat > /home/username/data.gz' - This was the exact command, and I get only 1 file

Comment: That’s not even remotely close to what you wrote in your question.

Comment: Hi Mark, Thanks for your answer and edit; I should have been careful by posting my full code here, as I'm a newbie, I didn't get the difference

Answer (score 0):

gzip compress files ant not directory structure.

by default, gzip add .gz at the end of a file name.

in your case, you can simply run 'gzip *' and you will have two separate .gz files

to compress a structure, you can use tar with z option to compress directly, without pipeling to gz.

Comment: I do a gunzip and all I get is the first file, with the combined size of the two that were a part of the original compression. How do I split them again is the question

Comment: Get the sizes of the original files and use `dd` to split it. If you don't have the sizes of the original files, the information is lost.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll try this